# SAS Calculate the proportion of two datasets

Tags: sas

I got two datasets, assume one has 100 observation and the other has 50. So, the proportion of these two datasets is 100/50=2. Does anyone know how to calculate this number in SAS and save it for later programming? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are loads of ways to get dataset obs, such as: proc SQL insert into, proc contents output, using SASHELP tables, using the end= statement in a datastep.

However I like doing it with SAS macro vars (using %let and %sysfunc) as it makes you like a badass. You want to look like a badass right?
Something like this (I don't have SAS open in front of me to test so the syntax might be slightly wrong):

```
%macro getobs(mydata);
    %let data_open=%sysfunc(OPEN(&mydata.,IN));
    %let NOBS_&mydata.=%sysfunc(ATTRN(&data_open,NLOBS));
    %let data_close=%sysfunc(CLOSE(&data_open));
%mend;
```

Then you should be able to use the NOBS_&mydata vars to get your required proportion value (although you might need a `%global NOBS_&mydata.` statement in the macro .... I'm not sure). Something like:

```
%let proportion = &NOBS_data1 / &NOBS_data2;
```

Play around with it and see what you come up with.

Comment: You are correct - the macro will need a `%global NOBS_&mydata.;` or the new variable will be lost when the macro finished executing. Also, use `%let proportion = %sysevalf(&NOBS_data1 / &NOBS_data2);` or the macro variable proportion will have a value like `100 / 50` instead of `2`.

Alternatively, just remove the `%let NOBS_&mydata.=` from the start of the 3rd line of code and then this macro can behave like a function. Then `%let proportion = %sysevalf(%getobs(data1) / %getobs(data2))` should give the required result.